# JOIN Query working in sql server 2008, unable to load data in datagridview only shows heading

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, join, datagridview

I am trying to load data from different tables created in sql server 2008 based on the values selected from the combo boxes. I had written the query for the same which works perfectly in SQL Server 2008 but doesn't load any data in datagridview but shows the heading of the required data fields from database.

I am completely struck ed. There are no errors. Application works completely fine. Even the query itself is able to execute in query builder.

So I request you all to get me out of this problem. Thanks in advance for any help.

Here is the code:

```
public partial class ViewTimeTable : Form
{
  SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand();
  DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
  int d_id, y_id;
  public ViewTimeTable()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }      
  private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    try
    {
        d_id = Convert.ToInt32(cmbDepartment.SelectedValue);
        y_id = Convert.ToInt32(cmbDepartment.SelectedValue);
        SqlDataAdapter dap=null;

        string query = "SELECT TimeTable.Day,TimeTable.FromTime,TimeTable.ToTime,
        Teachers.TName,Subject.SubName  FROM (TimeTable INNER JOIN Teachers ON 
        TimeTable.T_id = Teachers.T_id INNER JOIN Subject ON TimeTable.Sub_id = 
        Subject.Sub_id) Where TimeTable.D_id=" + d_id + " AND TimeTable.Y_id=" + 
        y_id + "";
        cm.CommandText = query;
        da.Action(cm);

        dap=da.GetDataAdapter(cm);

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        dap.Fill(table);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    }
   }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Do any other, simpler queries work?

Comment: Are you sure you are connected to the same database?  And, can you edit the question to include the query after variable substitution (print out `query`).  I suspect the problem is either the database or the variables being inserted into the string.

Comment: @RBarryYoung yes of course simple query works!

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes i m connected to same database. If as per you there is a problem in database then why the query is working in Query Builder in same solution. And for the query just substitute did=1 and yid=1 in the above query removing the variables and "".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I read the code, I see:

```
    d_id = Convert.ToInt32(cmbDepartment.SelectedValue);
    y_id = Convert.ToInt32(cmbDepartment.SelectedValue);
```

To my eyes, these are setting `d_id` and `y_id` to the same value.  I suspect that you want them set to different values.

The reason your query is not working is because no rows meet the condition.  If you print out the query after variable substitution, the problem would be obvious.

Comment: thanks gordon! so simple mistake, yet i was unable to spot it. That's how testing work various eye can spot various bugs. Sometimes even we make silly mistake. Sorry for the trouble and thanks for the help.